# Does JSONP scale? How many JSONP requests can I send before my page fills up with <script> tags?

Tags: json, jsonp

Based on [Please explain JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/please-explain-jsonp), I understand that JSONP can be used to get around the same-origin policy.

But in order to do that, the page must use a `<script>` tag.

I know that pages can dynamically emit new script tags, such as with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language='javascript'>

  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" ' + 
                 'id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" ' +
                 'src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');
  var contentloadtag=document.getElementById("contentloadtag");
  contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (this.readyState=="complete") { init(); }
  }
</script>
```

(the above works in IE, don't think it works in FF).

... but does this mean, effectively, that every JSONP call requires me to emit another `<script>` tag into the document?  Can I remove the `<script>` tags that are done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, every request yields a new `<script>` tag, and yes, you can remove `<script>` tags when you're done using the data that it provides to you.

You should consider using a Javascript library for JSONP. [OX.AJAST](http://ox.no/posts/ajast-cross-domain-rest-calls-using-json-injection) is a simple library I wrote some time ago for doing asynchronous request through script tags (i.e. JSONP) across browsers. [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) also supports JSONP if you're already using that.

Comment: Do those lirbaries you mentioned remove the `<script>` tags automatically?  or do I need to do that manually?

Comment: OX.AJAST does it, I don't know if YUI does it.